# Java Methods when working with Swing - It is possible to call event method in another event method in same class?

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe, call

so I am new to java and using right now swing. I have an method (first method) that does some code when I type in specific jField and release key. 
I also have jCheckBox, so when I tick or untick checkbox it does some action, this is second method.

So I want when I tick or untick checkbox make it call my first method and first method must do it's code. But it seems I have problem and I can't call this method fro some reason.

[Part of first method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2RKh.png):

```
   private void bruttoTextFieldKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {  
       //code
}
```

[Second method trying to call first method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRmlX.png):

```
private void pensionCheckBoxStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEventevt) {                                             
       bruttoTextFieldKeyReleased();
}
```

[Those methods were created with this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5WIL.png)

And this is hint, but I am not sure what I need to do, it required some KeyEvent? I just want launch one method from another, not putting any value and not returning.

[Error Hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u61QO.png)

Comment: Event based methods, work the same as normal methods in Java, in this case the problem is that you are not passing a required keyEvent to the `bruttoTextFieldKeyReleased` method you are trying to call.

You could create a KeyEvent and pass it to the method, but I doubt this is what you want to do. Instead consider, extracting the logic from `bruttoTextFieldKeyReleased` to another method, say `methodB()` and just call `methodB()` when the check box state changes.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but could you tell me more about passing KeyEvent or what do you mean by extracting logic? Does you mean make different method and call this method using event methods??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a bit on Luvy's comment, and convert it into an answer using your code.

Right now, the first method takes a KeyEvent, and looks like this:

```
private void bruttoTextFieldKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
  double salaryBrutto = Double.parseDouble(bruttoTextField.getText());

  double taxPensRound;
  if (pensionCheckBox.isSelected()) {
    double taxPens = salaryBrutto * TAX_PENS;
    //more code
```

Going by the screenshots, it looks like you most likely auto-created it from a GUI builder, and are not using the KeyEvent evt parameter.  You aren't able to call this method without passing in a KeyEvent, which is why pensionCheckBoxStateChanged cannot call it.

Luvy's suggestion would be to create a new method out of the bruttoTextFieldKeyReleased button, so afterwords you would have two methods:

```
private void bruttoTextFieldKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
  calculatePensionInformation();
  //maybe do something with evt later on
}
```

and

```
private void calculatePensionInformation() {
  double salaryBrutto = Double.parseDouble(bruttoTextField.getText());

  double taxPensRound;
  if (pensionCheckBox.isSelected()) {
    double taxPens = salaryBrutto * TAX_PENS;
    //more code
```

}

At this point, you could change your existing second method to be:

```
private void pensionCheckBoxStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEventevt) {                                             
   calculatePensionInformation();
}
```

And it would work as expected, since calculatePensionInformation requires no parameters, and you are passing in no parameters.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, it works as I wanted. I've put vote on answer.